# register a click event and calling the same event

Tags: jquery

I need to register a click event and need to call the same event when I click ("$p2") element

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#p1").on( 'click', function( event) { 
                    console.log( 'clicked = ', $(this).text() );

                    $("#p2").on( 'click', function( event ) {       
                    $("p").trigger( 'click' ); 
                        })
                })

            });
        </script>

        <style>
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        This is a scratch html.
        <br>
        <p id="p1">This is paragraph - p1</p>
        <p id="p2">This is paragraph - p2</p>
    </body>
    </table>
</html>
```

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Wchfk/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is multiple selector

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#p1, #p2").on('click', function (event) {
         console.log('clicked = ', $(this).text());
     })
 });
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Wchfk/)